# Get disk type in QT

Tags: linux, windows, qt

I want to get disk type (SSD or HDD) in QT. I've checked `QStorageInfo` but I could not find anything useful for my purpose. By the way I need a solution that's work on both Windows and Linux.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For linux, you can tell whether the kernel has detected a SSD disk by reading special file

```
/sys/block/<disk>/queue/rotational
```

For instance, `cat /sys/block/sda/queue/rotational` writes `1` if sda disk is HDD and `0` if it's SSD.

For Windows, you can open a drive by opening special file `\\.\PhysicalDrive<number>`, for instance `\\.\PhysicalDrive0`. It can the be used with [`DeviceIOControl`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa363216(v=vs.85).aspx) to query properties, using [`IOCTL_STORAGE_QUERY_PROPERTY`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800830(v=vs.85).aspx) IO control. It seems [`StorageDeviceSeekPenaltyProperty`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ff800828(v=vs.85).aspx) may be what you're after, as HDD have a seek penalty while SSD don't. Alas I don't have a windows environment around to test right now.

For portability, I highly doubt such system-dependent information is available in a portable way. You'll have to use `#ifdef`/`#else`/`#endif` macros to select an implementation depending on current target.

Comment: "I highly doubt such system-dependent information is available in a portable way" Yes, it's true. Even Java which boasts to be multiplatform and all that doesn't provide such a way as far as I know. MacOS (which is not required here) also has its own way.