# Get HDD MediaType from Win32_DiskDrive

Tags: winapi, wql

I am trying to get the hard disk media from `Win32_DiskDrive API`. However, it returns me all SSD and HDD drives. I want to get only the HDD disks. Is it supported by Win32_DiskDrive API? Below is the query forget all hard disk media.

```
SELECT * FROM Win32_DiskDrive WHERE MediaType = "Fixed hard disk media"
```

I've tried the Get-PhysicalDisk in Powershell, with which we can filter HDD drives, but I want it as part of the WQL query. Thanks in advance.

Comment: look for https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23363115/detecting-ssd-in-windows and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44020793/get-disk-type-in-qt/44021432#44021432

Comment: You can use `MSFT_PhysicalDisk` with WMI.